# TypeError: arr.map is not a function in js, and nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am getting this error, but the code was working now it's not working somehow.

```
TypeError: arr.map is not a function
```

## Am I doing something wrong?

```
export const footerAdapter = (footerData) => {
  const arr = footerData[0].attributes['items']
    return arr.map((md) => {
      return {
        link: md.link,
        title: md.title
      };
  });
};
```

## Update:

I am trying yo fetch this data:

```
[
    {
        "attributes": {
            "items": {
                "title": "Hello world",
                "link": "/Home",
                "__typename": "ComponentFooterFooterItems"
            },
            "__typename": "Footer"
        },
        "__typename": "FooterEntity"
    },
]
```

Comment: What type of object is `arr`? It's obviously not an array as you expect.

Comment: This is a wrong syntax.
footerData[].attributes['items']

Comment: footerData[].attributes['items'] could be undefined or null. If so it will give you that error

Comment: @Engam yes that is why it gives the error, so how to avoid getting the error?

Comment: @Barmar it's an object.

Comment: You can only `map()` over arrays, unless the object provides its own `map()` method.

Comment: Items is not an array

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, the items is an object

Answer (score 0):

Your data could be undefined or null and therefor it gives you an error. So you should write in a fallback:

```
export const footerAdapter = (footerData) => {
  if (!footerData || !footerData[0] || !footerData[0].attributes || !footerData[0].attributes['items'] || footerData[0].attributes['items'].length <= 0) return []
  const arr = footerData[0].attributes['items'];
  return arr.map((md) => {
      return {
        link: md.link,
        title: md.title
      };
  });
};
```

This will return an empty array if footerData[0].attributes['items'] is undefined or null;

**Edit**

The .map wont work because your 'items' isnt an array. If something has changed, this is what is wrong.

But you can change it to

```
export const footerAdapter = (footerData) => {
  if (!footerData || !footerData[0] || !footerData[0].attributes || !footerData[0].attributes['items'] || footerData[0].attributes['items']) return {link: '', title: ''}
   const obj = footerData[0].attributes['items']

   return {
      link: obj.link,
      title: obj.title
   }
}
```

**Edit 2**

If items for some reason sometimes are an array and sometimes are an object, you need to do some typechecking. One way to solve it is to:

```
export const footerAdapter = (footerData) => {
  if (!footerData || !footerData[0] || !footerData[0].attributes || !footerData[0].attributes['items']) {
    return [{link: '', title: ''}];
  }
  const arr = footerData[0].attributes['items'];
  if (arr && arr[0] && arr.length > 0) {
  return arr.map((md) => {
    return {
      link: md.link,
      title: md.title
    };
  });
  } else if (arr && arr.link && arr.title) {
    return [{link: arr.link, title: arr.title}];
  } else {
    return [{link: '', title: ''}]
  }
};
```

The above code is a litle ugly, but should work both if your items property is an array (like before) or an object in your example. With an handler which returns `[{link: '', title: ''}]` doesn't mach one of the two first strucktures.

Comment: Shouldn't the `if` statement be before you assign to `arr`?

Comment: ah yes,  by bad, edits it now :)

Comment: Nop, the same error.

Comment: No, the same thing again:(

Comment: could you try to put in a console.log(footerData) in your function to check how your data looks like when it is passed in to the function? (before the new if statement)

Comment: I did, and i put the console result in the question I updated you can see it now.

Comment: Something is so hell wrong, let me see more about what I did.

By the way thank you

Comment: no problem. My last edit might work. in my first edit I just retured an object an expected that the items was always an object. But there could be something wrong with the origin of data. And where where you call the footerAdapter probably expects an array of objects. The last wil take care of both if the data is object or array, and it will always return an array of objects. For the two fallback if elses you could probably also return an empty array which might be best suited for your project.

Comment: Yeah. it worked but it does not return all the data, I tried something else, and now it's working well, but when I the testing it failed.

Answer (score 0):

The "TypeError: map is not a function" occurs when we call the map() method on an object that is not an array.

To solve the error, console.log the value you're calling the map() method on and make sure to only call the map method on valid arrays.

```
const obj = {};

// ⛔️ Uncaught TypeError: map is not a function
const result = obj.map(element => {
  return element + 1;
});
```

You can conditionally check if the value is an array by using the Array.isArray method.

```
const arr = 'test';

const result = Array.isArray(arr) ? arr.map(element => element + 1) : [];

console.log(result); // ️ []
```

Answer (score -1):

try fixing the error using arr?.map

Comment: Tried but didn't work

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Note your items is not an array so we need more code

Here I use reduce, assuming that by [0] you only want the first entry in your array

```js
const footerAdapter = footerData => Object.entries(footerData?.[0].attributes?.['items'] ?? {})
  .filter(([key,value])=> ["link","title"].includes(key))
  .reduce((acc, [key,value])=> (acc[key] = value, acc),{});


const fd1 = [{
  "attributes": {
    "items": {
      "title": "Hello world",
      "link": "/Home",
      "__typename": "ComponentFooterFooterItems"
    },
    "__typename": "Footer"
  },
  "__typename": "FooterEntity"
} ];

const fd2 = [{
  attributes: {}
}]

const arr1 = footerAdapter(fd1)
console.log(arr1)
const arr2 = footerAdapter(fd2)
console.log(arr2)
```

Array of objects

```js
const footerAdapter = footerData => Object.entries(footerData?.[0].attributes?.['items'] ?? {})
  .filter(([key,value])=> ["link","title"].includes(key))
  .map(([key,value])=> ({[key]:value}));


const fd1 = [{
  "attributes": {
    "items": {
      "title": "Hello world",
      "link": "/Home",
      "__typename": "ComponentFooterFooterItems"
    },
    "__typename": "Footer"
  },
  "__typename": "FooterEntity"
} ];

const fd2 = [{
  attributes: {}
}]

const arr1 = footerAdapter(fd1)
console.log(arr1)
const arr2 = footerAdapter(fd2)
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try and let you know.